# Copy entire Excel worksheet without formulas

Tags: excel, vba

Any recommendations please? I’ve tried

```
Ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(“tab”)
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(“tab”).UsedRange.Value = Ws.UsedRange.Value
```

but no luck

I would like to copy all of the info over to another file but have tried a few methods but gotten stuck

Comment: **unclear** if a cell contains a formula, do you want the copy to be the current **value** of the original or do you want the copy to **remain empty** ??

Comment: Yeah sorry I should’ve made that clear, any formulas to convert into their values ideally

Comment: And what exactly does "no luck" mean. What you posted should work, assuming you are referring to the correct sheets.

Comment: It only copies the first cell of the sheet, not every cell or row

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give something like this a try:

```
Sub KopyKat()
    Sheets("original").Cells.Copy
    Sheets("kopy").Cells.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
End Sub
```

*(use your own worksheet names)*

**EDIT#1:**

It is better if the `kopy` worksheet does not exist when we start:

We will

- copy the entire worksheet *(not just the cells)*
- rename the copy
- convert all formulas to values

```
Sub KopyKat2()
    With Sheets("original")
        .Copy after:=Sheets("original")
    End With

    With ActiveSheet
        .Name = "kopy"
        With .UsedRange
            .Value = .Value
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Now `kopy` also has all the formats as the original as well and column widths, row heights, etc.

Comment: Depending on the size of sheet you are copying, this method can eat up the memory. Might be worth considering clearing **clipboard**

Comment: @Zac  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: Will that not copy the formulas as well?

Comment: @Zac  **you are correct!** it **does** copy both formula and data, but ............... the ***.Value=.Value*** statement converts the formulas into values!

Comment: I was wondering what magic that was. Learn something new everyday. Thanks